# Easy way to horizontally flip images in dataset with json labels?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0

I'm using Tensorflow 2.0 with Python to train an image classifier. I'm using the file model_main_tf2.py to train the model, and have a dataset of images for training and testing. The images were annotated using the LabelMe tool in Python, which allows me to create polygon masks for a Mask RCNN.

What I would like to do is generate duplicates of all the training and test images, by flipping them horizontally. I can already do this easily in python, but I want to flip the JSON files that LabelMe generates, to save me from re-annotating the new flipped images. Is there a tool that allows me to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is under the Python tag - I assume you want this to be done in Python. Flipping can be done in `numpy`, `PIL`, or `opencv` (your choice).

```py
image = # some image translated to a numpy array
print(type(image))
>> numpy.ndarray

# np.fliplr will also do the trick
flipped_image_h = np.flip(image, axis=1) # flip horizontally

# np.flipud will also do the trick
flipped_image_v = np.flip(image, axis=0) # flip vertically

# Save flipped_image
```

[See the numpy docs for more info](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html)

Comment: Yes, in Python. I think I need the images flipping before I train the model with Tensorflow. I know it can be done on the fly, but I'm using Mask RCNN so I need to retain the object segmentation. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think there isn't an explicite way to do it. you just need to write a code that opens your JSon files and make the changes yourself

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32289928)